# Preventing repetitive items from being printed

Tags: java, object, for-loop, printing, while-loop

How do I check to see if an item is already in a list and prevent it from being added. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Before checkout
    Item list[] = new Item[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {   
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 2);

        if(random == 0)
            list[i] = new Perish();
        else
            list[i] = new Nonperish();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < list.length; j++)
            if(list[i].getName().equals(list[j].getName()))
            {
                int newRandom = (int)((Math.random() * 2));
                        if(newRandom == 0)
                            list[i] = new Perish();
                        else 
                            list[i] = new Nonperish();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @Adarsh I have to print a grocery list and I dont want repeat items to print on the receipt. I am trying to check and see if an item that has been created has the same name as another item in the list. If it has the same name, create a new object to get a different name. This needs to be checked to see if the item that was created also has the same name and I dont know how to do that.

Comment: But you are only creating an object every time. How is the name set ? From what I can see, the names would all be the same. Could you provide the code in Perish and Nonperish too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspite using an array try using HashSet. To make the object Item work in a HashSet you should override hasCode() and equals() methods. I assume that getName() returns String so these methods should be like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getName().hashCode();
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null){
        return false;
    }
    if(!o.getClass().equals(getClass())){
        return false;
    }
    return this.getName().equals(((Item)o).getName());
}
```

And then try using this code. At the end your array can't have any repeated item:

```
Item list[] = new Item[10];

Set<Item> itemSet = new HashSet();


for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{   

    do{
    int random = (int)(Math.random() * 2);

        if(random == 0)
            list[i] = new Perish();
        else
            list[i] = new Nonperish();

        if(itemSet.contains(list[i])){
            continue;
        }else {
            itemSet.add(list[i]);
            break;
        }
    }while(true);

}
```